# To sum column with condition

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have data in textfile. example.

```
A B C D E F
10 0 0.9775 39.3304 0.9311 60.5601
10 1 0.9802 32.3287 0.9433 56.1201
10 2 0.9816 39.9759 0.9446 54.0428
10 3 0.9737 37.8779 0.9419 56.3865
10 4 0.9798 34.9152 0.905 69.0879
10 5 0.9803 50.057 0.9201 64.6289
10 6 0.9805 39.1062 0.9093 68.4061
10 7 0.9781 33.8874 0.9327 60.7631
10 8 0.9802 32.5734 0.9376 60.9165
10 9 0.9798 32.3466 0.94 54.7645
11 0 0.9749 40.2712 0.9042 71.2873
11 1 0.9755 35.6546 0.9195 63.7436
11 2 0.9766 36.753 0.9507 51.7864
11 3 0.9779 35.6485 0.9371 59.2483
11 4 0.9803 35.2712 0.8833 79.0257
11 5 0.981 46.5462 0.9156 66.6951
11 6 0.9809 41.8181 0.8642 83.7533
11 7 0.9749 36.7484 0.9259 62.36
11 8 0.9736 36.8859 0.9395 58.1538
11 9 0.98 32.4069 0.9255 61.202
12 0 0.9812 37.2547 0.9121 68.1347
12 1 0.9808 31.4568 0.9372 55.9992
12 2 0.9813 36.5316 0.9497 53.1687
12 3 0.9803 33.1063 0.9051 69.8894
12 4 0.9786 35.0318 0.8968 72.9963
12 5 0.9756 63.441 0.9091 69.9482
12 6 0.9804 39.1602 0.9156 65.2399
12 7 0.976 35.5875 0.9248 62.6284
12 8 0.9779 33.7774 0.9416 56.3755
12 9 0.9804 32.0849 0.9401 55.2871
```

I want the sum of column C. With the condition that. Column A has a value that is unique (10 lines). Please advise me.

Comment: None of the column A have unique values. Do you mean you want to sum the rows grouped by column A?

Comment: @user1487724 which of these lines are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    next(f)
    d=dict()
    for x in f:
        if x.split()[0] not in d:
            d[x.split()[0]]=float(x.split()[2])
        else:
            d[x.split()[0]]+=float(x.split()[2])
```

**output:**

```
{'11': 9.7756, '10': 9.791699999999999, '12': 9.7925}
```

Comment: you have not taken care of the condition `With the condition that. Column A has a value that is unique (10 lines)`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L=map(str.split, """10  0   0.9775  39.3304 0.9311  60.5601
... 10  1   0.9802  32.3287 0.9433  56.1201
... 10  2   0.9816  39.9759 0.9446  54.0428
... 10  3   0.9737  37.8779 0.9419  56.3865
... 10  4   0.9798  34.9152 0.905   69.0879
... 10  5   0.9803  50.057  0.9201  64.6289
... 10  6   0.9805  39.1062 0.9093  68.4061
... 10  7   0.9781  33.8874 0.9327  60.7631
... 10  8   0.9802  32.5734 0.9376  60.9165
... 10  9   0.9798  32.3466 0.94    54.7645
... 11  0   0.9749  40.2712 0.9042  71.2873
... 11  1   0.9755  35.6546 0.9195  63.7436
... 11  2   0.9766  36.753  0.9507  51.7864
... 11  3   0.9779  35.6485 0.9371  59.2483
... 11  4   0.9803  35.2712 0.8833  79.0257
... 11  5   0.981   46.5462 0.9156  66.6951
... 11  6   0.9809  41.8181 0.8642  83.7533
... 11  7   0.9749  36.7484 0.9259  62.36
... 11  8   0.9736  36.8859 0.9395  58.1538
... 11  9   0.98    32.4069 0.9255  61.202
... 12  0   0.9812  37.2547 0.9121  68.1347
... 12  1   0.9808  31.4568 0.9372  55.9992
... 12  2   0.9813  36.5316 0.9497  53.1687
... 12  3   0.9803  33.1063 0.9051  69.8894
... 12  4   0.9786  35.0318 0.8968  72.9963
... 12  5   0.9756  63.441  0.9091  69.9482
... 12  6   0.9804  39.1602 0.9156  65.2399
... 12  7   0.976   35.5875 0.9248  62.6284
... 12  8   0.9779  33.7774 0.9416  56.3755
... 12  9   0.9804  32.0849 0.9401  55.2871""".split("\n"))
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D = defaultdict(float)
>>> for a,b,c,d,e,f in L:
...     D[a] += float(c)
... 
>>> D
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {'11': 9.7756, '10': 9.791699999999999, '12': 9.7925})
>>> dict(D.items())
{'11': 9.7756, '10': 9.791699999999999, '12': 9.7925}
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

while <file; do
    ((a[$1]+=$3))
done
print -C a
```

output

```
([10]=9.7917 [11]=9.7756 [12]=9.7925)
```

Requires the undocumented FILESCAN compile-time option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum grouped by A value:

```
awk '{sums[$1] += $3} END {for (sum in sums) print sum, sums[sum]}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open("file.txt","rU") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # read header
    reader.next()
    # summarize
    a_values = []
    sum = 0
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] not in a_values:
            a_values.append(row[0])
            sum += float(row[2])
```