# How to combine numerical columnar data in Python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner at Python and I have no idea how to do the following:

I have a text file of numerical data in this form:

```
  
1461.5  5   9   -18 32
1462    21  5   -6  32
1462    5   4   -23 32
1462.5  17  6   -7  30
1464    11  6   -14 31
1464    8   2   -22 32
1464.5  9   5   -17 31
1465    6   16  -7  29
1467    9   6   -17 32
1467.5  14  9   -8  31
1469.5  13  5   -12 30
1469.5  14  10  -7  31
1471    15  7   -9  31
1471    12  8   -10 30
1471.5  13  11  -7  31
1472    27  4   -1  32
1472    7   13  -8  28
1472    8   8   -14 30
```

I would like to find out how to identify rows that have the same value in the first column, add the corresponding items in the other columns, and remove the duplicate entries in the first column so that the resulting output looks like this:

```
1461.5  5   9   -18 32
1462    26  9   -29 64
1462.5  17  6   -7  30
1464    19  8   -36 63
1464.5  9   5   -17 31
1465    6   16  -7  29
1467    9   6   -17 32
1467.5  14  9   -8  31
1469.5  27  15  -19 61
1471    27  15  -19 61
1471.5  13  11  -7  31
1472    42  25  -23 90
```

If it would make things less complicated, all the numbers in the first column could be rounded into integers ahead of time (it will have little effect on the subsequent computations).

Note: The actual text file contains 23,000 rows. The values in the first column are in ascending order.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239815/to-sum-column-with-condition/11239899#comment14768205_11239899

Comment: Thanks avasal. I will study the answers for that question.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
D = defaultdict(list)
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for row in f:
        row = row.split()
        D[float(row[0])].append([int(x) for x in row[1:]])

for k,v in sorted(D.items()):
    print k, [sum(x) for x in zip(*v)]
```

**Edit:** Since the input file is always in order, you can do better

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for k,v in groupby(f, key=lambda x:x.split()[0]):
        print k, map(sum, zip(*[map(int, x.split()[1:]) for x in v]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and it gives me something to learn from. I sort of follow what is occurring in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
with open('data.txt') as data:
   d={}
   for row in data:
      l=row.split()
      key=l[0]
      l=[int(e) for e in l[1:]]
      if key in d:
         d[key]=[x+y for x,y in zip(l,d[key])]
      else:
         d[key]=l  

for e in sorted(d.keys()):
    t=tuple([e]+list(map(str,d[e])))
    print("{:<7} {:<3} {:<3} {:<3} {:<3}".format(*t))
```

Prints:

```
1461.5  5   9   -18 32 
1462    26  9   -29 64 
1462.5  17  6   -7  30 
1464    19  8   -36 63 
1464.5  9   5   -17 31 
1465    6   16  -7  29 
1467    9   6   -17 32 
1467.5  14  9   -8  31 
1469.5  27  15  -19 61 
1471    27  15  -19 61 
1471.5  13  11  -7  31 
1472    42  25  -23 90
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense to me (I am a beginner).

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package for this type of work.

Load data:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """
1461.5  5   9   -18 32
1462    21  5   -6  32
1462    5   4   -23 32
1462.5  17  6   -7  30
1464    11  6   -14 31
1464    8   2   -22 32
1464.5  9   5   -17 31
1465    6   16  -7  29
1467    9   6   -17 32
1467.5  14  9   -8  31
1469.5  13  5   -12 30
1469.5  14  10  -7  31
1471    15  7   -9  31
1471    12  8   -10 30
1471.5  13  11  -7  31
1472    27  4   -1  32
1472    7   13  -8  28
1472    8   8   -14 30
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' *', engine='python', names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

The `df` dataframe now contains your example data:

```
df
Out[90]: 
         a   b   c   d   e
0   1461.5   5   9 -18  32
1   1462.0  21   5  -6  32
2   1462.0   5   4 -23  32
3   1462.5  17   6  -7  30
4   1464.0  11   6 -14  31
5   1464.0   8   2 -22  32
6   1464.5   9   5 -17  31
7   1465.0   6  16  -7  29
8   1467.0   9   6 -17  32
9   1467.5  14   9  -8  31
10  1469.5  13   5 -12  30
11  1469.5  14  10  -7  31
12  1471.0  15   7  -9  31
13  1471.0  12   8 -10  30
14  1471.5  13  11  -7  31
15  1472.0  27   4  -1  32
16  1472.0   7  13  -8  28
17  1472.0   8   8 -14  30
```

Grouping this dataframe by the first column, and summing all the other columns, is just one line:

```
df2 = df.groupby('a').agg(sum).reset_index()
df2
Out[92]: 
         a   b   c   d   e
0   1461.5   5   9 -18  32
1   1462.0  26   9 -29  64
2   1462.5  17   6  -7  30
3   1464.0  19   8 -36  63
4   1464.5   9   5 -17  31
5   1465.0   6  16  -7  29
6   1467.0   9   6 -17  32
7   1467.5  14   9  -8  31
8   1469.5  27  15 -19  61
9   1471.0  27  15 -19  61
10  1471.5  13  11  -7  31
11  1472.0  42  25 -23  90
```